# Match (a AND b) vs (a OR b) in PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to search through some files in `PHP` and I want to give the user a choice between matching any or every term.

E.g.: `Search terms: [apple,banana]`

Is it possible to return only files that have both words in it?

Also my OR would use the following:

`$s_terms = "(" . implode("|", explode(",", $s_terms)) . ")";`

I want to separate terms with `,` and use it in a `RegEx` match like `(apple|banana)`. Does the above code do that?

Thank you in forward

EDIT:

The other question did not answer my question, but I found something that works:
`(.*apple.*banana.*)`

Comment: Your code correctly converts `a,b` into `(a|b)`. But that will match files with any of the words, it won't require that they have ALL the words.

Comment: @Barmar That is what I guessed, but Is there a way to look for ALL the words, or will I have to separately match every word in the file?